# Comparing with sliced object string is not working with filter method

Tags: javascript, filter

i have a array of object like this.

```
const ExpensesData=[
  {
    title: 'Toilet Paper',
    amount: 94.12,
    date: "2022-09-02",
  },
  {
    title: 'New TV', 
    amount: 799.49, 
    date: "2021-08-02",
  }
]
```

i am trying to filter objects base upon year.
i tried like this. but, no luck. it looks simple but don't know what is the issue.

```
const filteredData = ExpensesData.filter((e)=> e.date.slice(0,4) == "2021")
```

This statement works fine as it return first 4 character of the string.

```
const aa = ExpensesData[0].date.slice(0,4);
```

All i am doing is comparing it with.

Comment: I'm confused, what is not working exactly? What output do you expect?

Comment: filteredData should return an array of object where date year is 2021

Comment: And it does it! (:

Comment: yes, it does. i don't KNOW what was the issue. i was grinding myself for an hour.

Comment: Can somebody help me what shall i do with this question ? shall i delete it or shalli leave it as it is ?

Comment: Not sure, maybe I'd delete it

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution.

Maybe it suits you

```
const ExpensesData =[
 {
  title: 'Toilet Paper',
  amount: 94.12,
  date: "2022-08-03",
 },
 {
  title: 'New TV', 
  amount: 799.49, 
  date: "2022-08-02",
 }
]

const dates = ExpensesData.map(el => el.date);

dates.sort((a, b) => {
 let year = [+a.slice(0, 4), +b.slice(0, 4)];
 if (comparison(year)) return comparison(year);

 let month = [+a.slice(5, 7), +b.slice(5, 7)];
 if (comparison(month)) return comparison(month);

 let day = [+a.slice(8, a.length), +b.slice(8, b.length)];
 if (comparison(day)) return comparison(day);
});

function comparison(arr) {
 if (arr[0] > arr[1]) {
  return 1;
 } else if (arr[0] < arr[1]) {
  return -1;
 }
}
```